# how to get 'country_name' selected in select option react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

I have an country list and I can get ID country list,how to get country name?

my state

```
this.state = {
   MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:'',
   MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME:''
}
```

this html select

```
<Form.Group controlId="countryList">
    <Form.Label><b>Country</b></Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="select" ref="idCountry" onClick={this.handleSelect}>
     {dataCountry}
    </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>

const dataCountry = this.state.country.map(countryList=> {
   return(
      <option key={countryList.country_id} value={countryList.country_id}>
          {countryList.country_name} //how to get country name?
       </option>
      )
})
```

this is my event

```
handleSelect(){
  if (this.refs.idCountry) {
      this.setState({
        MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:this.refs.idCountry.value.
        MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME:
      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach though manipulating state directly not recommended.

```
  <Form.Group controlId="countryList">
        <Form.Label><b>Country</b></Form.Label>
        <Form.Control as="select" ref="idCountry" onClick={(e) => this.handleSelect(e)}>
         {dataCountry}
        </Form.Control>
    </Form.Group>

    const dataCountry = this.state.country.map(countryList=> {
       return(
          <option key={countryList.country_id} value={countryList.country_id}>
              {countryList.country_name} //how to get country name?
           </option>
          )
    })


    handleSelect = (e)=>{
      if (this.refs.idCountry) {
          this.setState({
            MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:this.refs.idCountry.value.
            MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME: this.state.country[e.target.value].country_name
          })
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass it along with id in value={} as an object an then simply get it. Idk if it's best practice. But I hope it's useful.

```
<option ... value={{ id: country_id, name: country_name  }}>
```

smth like that ^